# PHP trim not working

Tags: php, trim

I m trying to get rid of the trailing comma my sql statemen using trim but it doesnt seem to work

```
if(isset($_POST['report'])){
    //====
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO weekly_repo ( hospnme, disease, week, under5, above5, dat) VALUES ';
    $week = intval($_POST['current_week']);
    $diseases = $_POST['diseases'];

    foreach($diseases as $disease){

        $sql .= ' ( "' . filterString($_POST['hospital']). '", "' . filterString($disease['disease']) . '", ' . $week . ', ' . intval($disease['under_5']) . ', ' . intval($disease['over_5']) . ', NOW()), ';

    }
    $sql = trim($sql, '\,');
    // ended up doing this
    //$sql = substr($sql, 0, strrpos($sql, ',')) . ';';
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

}
```

Comment: Get rid of the slash. You don't need it. $sql = trim($sql, ','); Or just use `$sql = substr($sql, -1)`.

Comment: Since there is an extra space, you'd need `rtrim(…, ", ")`. Better yet, build an array, join that into the string when you have all data pairs. Which avoids the trimming kludge.

Comment: Thank buddies! But  in the PHP manual they escape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape `\` the comma.  A better approach might be to construct an array and then `implode()`:

```
foreach($diseases as $disease){
    $sql[] = ' ( "' . filterString($_POST['hospital']). '", "' . filterString($disease['disease']) . '", ' . $week . ', ' . intval($disease['under_5']) . ', ' . intval($disease['over_5']) . ', NOW()), ';
}
$sql = implode(',', $sql);
```